# How can I break out of this Promise for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

**EDIT:** I know how to get it working using async/await but unfortunately, I can't use it as it's not widely supported (especially iOS 10, Internet Explorers etc). So I need a promises only way.

I am very new to Promises so I am stuck. I have this for loop which I want to break out of whenever i equals to 2 (just for example). I have tried putting the `reject` but it still continues on until `i<10`. I want it to stop when my condition is met.

```js
for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < 10; i++) {
  p = p.then(_ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
      if (i == 2) {
        reject("BREAK HERE");
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  })).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Current output:

```
0
1
2
BREAK HERE
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I want it to just be:

```
0
1
2
BREAK HERE
```

Comment: The `.catch()` is stopping it from actually failing.

Comment: Your `catch` doesn't propagate the error

Comment: @TKoL Then it prints an ugly error in console: (node:66142) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined (node:66142) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:66142) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve with this code? What's your goal here? (I don't mean in the "break out of this promise loop" sense, but in a more abstract sense.) As it stands, your code looks very convoluted.

Comment: I am esp. wondering about your `p = Promise.resolve()` part. Why define a always-successful promise only to attach a success handler in the for-loop? And then you create yet another promise. Why?

Comment: @k0pernikus i am trying to use a similar code to upload files. I need it so that the files should only continue uploading if the previous files have succeeded. Else I need it to throw an error. I am very new to web development and promises so my code might be convoluted but this was an example code I got from SO.

Comment: So you want to upload files sequentially while using an async upload method? And fail the entire process, as soon as one fails?

Comment: @PranoyC is there any reason why using `async/await` is not an option here? Because that would make what you're trying to achieve much easier.

Comment: @TKoL yes, I was able to get it working using `async/await` but unfortunately, I can't use it as it's not widely supported (especially iOS 10, Internet Explorers etc).

Comment: @k0pernikus yes, that's exactly what I am trying to achieve. Since `async/await` isn't supported widely, I need to use promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Just dont resolve and the sequence will stop

```js
for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < 10; i++) {
  p = p.then(_ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("i",i);
      if (i == 2) {
        console.log("break here")
        
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  })).catch(err => {
    console.log("err",err);
  });
}
```

But as this code itself intents to sequence async calls one should think about doing so:

```js
// repeated call
next(
  0/*state*/, 
  i=>i<2/*match*/, 
  i=>i+1/*increment*/,     
  asyncCallPromisefied/*promise|promise[]*/, 
  [0]/*args*/
)
.catch(console.log)


// traverse array
next(
  0/*state*/, 
  i => i < 6/*match*/, 
  i => i + 1/*increment*/,
  asyncChain()/*promise|promise[]*/, 
  [0]/*args*/,
  0/*[promise[] index]*/
)
.catch(console.log)


// helper
function next(state, match, increment, action, args, pointer = 0/**inactive**/){
  if(match(state))
  if(Array.isArray(action)){
     
     return pointer < action.length
      ? action[pointer](...args)
      .then(i => next(
        increment(state), 
        match, 
        increment, 
        action, 
        [i],
        pointer + 1
      ))
      : undefined;
  } else {
    return action(...args)
    .then(i => next(
      increment(state), 
      match, 
      increment, 
      action, 
      [i]
    ))
  }
}



// wrapper
function asyncCall(i, callback){ 
  return setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i == 2 ? 'break here': i);
    callback(null, ++i);
  }, Math.random() * 1000)
}

function asyncCallPromisefied(i){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    asyncCall(i, function(err, args){
      if(err){
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(args)
      }
    })
  })
}

function asyncChain(){return [
  function(i){console.log("chain",i);return Promise.resolve(i)},
  function(i){console.log("chain",i);return Promise.resolve(i)},
 function(i){console.log("chain",i);return Promise.resolve(i)},
  asyncCallPromisefied,
  function(i){console.log("chain",i);return Promise.resolve(i)},
]}
```

Comment: This would potentially be a memory leak though if you did this loads and loads of times.

Comment: @PranoyC The for loop still makes no sense. There is no need to create a `p = Promise.resolve()` . Furthermore, the not-resolved promises will remain pending forever hogging up memory.

Comment: @k0pernikus p is scoped within for loop and will fizzle thus gets garbage collected - also does the promise-chain. But I agree this is one of the bad ways to make subsequent calls - i will clean this up.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `catch`, otherwise, the error will be caught and handled. To log rather than error, use `console.log`:

```js
try {

  for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < 10; i++) {
    p = p.then(_ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
        if (i == 2) {
          reject(console.log("BREAK HERE"));
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      }, Math.random() * 1000)
    }));
  }

} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: This sort of works but prints an ugly error in console: `(node:66142) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:66142) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:66142) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Answer (score 0):

In any case, your code will always execute 10 times, since setTimeout is asynchronous operation and till the time your condition `reject("BREAK HERE")` is met, already promise is chained ten times.

This is what you can do, though it looks messy :(

```js
for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < 10; i++) {
  p = p.then(data => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if(data && data.isRejected){
        resolve({ isRejected: true })
        return;
      }
      console.log(i);
      if (i == 2) {
        reject("BREAK HERE");
      } else {
        resolve({});
      }
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  })).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    /* add this line */
    return { isRejected: true };
  });
}
```

Returning a object from catch(instead of throwing) will mark the promise as resolved. more in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
This will provide you desired result

Comment: The explanation is good, but the output of your code is not what the OP asking for:  `BREAK HERE` should be logged only once...

Comment: This isn't what I want. I don't want it to print `BREAK HERE` more than once.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you want to sequentially work one promise after anothe. You then want to abort as soon as the first promise fails.

To ensure execution order, you have to do it like this in a for loop, though you lose the actual benefit of concurrent runtime. This code will run sequentually:

```
const delay = async () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), Math.random() * 1e3);

const myUpload = async (file) => {
    await delay();

    if (file === 2) {
        return Promise.reject(`COULD NOT UPLOAD ${file}`);
    } else {
        console.log("uploaded file", file);

        return;
    }

};

const uploadFilesSequentually = async (files) => {
    for (const file of files) {
        await myUpload(file); // this will create, and wait for the promise to finish or fail, only then the for loop continues
    }
};
```

---

If you were not to care about the order of execution and could allow for concurrency, I'd do something like this:

```
const promises = myFiles.map(myUpload); // all promises are now pending and will resolve in different orders
Promise.all(promises) // returns its own promise then resolves once all of them have succeded or is rejected as soon as one is rejected
    .then((result) => console.log("everything uploaded"))
    .catch(console.error);
```

(The result of `Promise.all` would keep the order of the results though. So even if the third promise resolves before the first, the result would be `[resultPromise1, resultPrimise2, resultPromise3, ... ]`)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use `async/await` as it's not widely supported. Lots of my customers are on older browsers (IE, iOS 10) and it's not supported there.

Comment: @PranoyC You could use babel and polyfills for older browsers. I try to add a non-async-await answer though if I find the time. The idea of it does not change though.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure out the solution by simply "not `resolve` and the sequence stops". No need for `reject` https://stackoverflow.com/a/57763342/1634905

Answer (score 0):

For now, I ended up using a different way to achieve this without Promises:

```
var i=0;

function fetchNext(){
    if (i==2) {
        console.log("BREAK HERE");
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
            i++;
            fetchNext();
        }, Math.random() * 1000);
    }
}

fetchNext();
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `.catch` in the loop and deal with it after.

```
let p = Promise.resolve();
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  p = p.then(_ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
      if (i == 2) {
        reject("BREAK HERE");
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  }));
}

p.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```